# Setup New Relic without their gradle plugin

Tags: android, newrelic

Working on an android project and the requirement is to not to use the gradle plugin but only the SDK and call the APIs on our own so no instrumentation by the plugin.

It doesn’t seem to work because after starting it logs a bunch of errors.

```
com.newrelic.android: Agent.getBuildId() was unable to find a valid build Id. Crashes and handled exceptions will not be accepted.
com.newrelic.android: Invalid (null or empty) build ID detected! Crash will be ignored by collector.
com.newrelic.android: ExceptionHelper: java.util.UUID:fromString(UUID.java:194) RandomUUID[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] Invalid UUID string: 
com.medco.medcopharmacy E/com.newrelic.android: Harvest instance is not running! Session duration will be invalid
com.medco.medcopharmacy E/com.newrelic.android: AgentDataReporter not initialized
com.medco.medcopharmacy E/com.newrelic.android: HandledException: exception java.lang.Exception failed to record data.
```

Looks like the plugin generates a config file NewRelicConfig which i won’t have by not using the plugin. Tried to add it manually but it generates a BUILD_ID which I am not sure about...

Any idea how to initialize the library correctly without using the new relic plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use their plugin?

Comment: It was a requirement from above me. The plugin is a black box and instrument things and we can't see that in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Posted the question on New Relic's discussion board and wanted to share the answer I've got there.

Looks like the SDK is not going to work without the gradle plugin unfortunately because it can't be initialized without the gradle plugin and bytecode transformer (instrumentation)

> The agent-gradle-plugin includes the Instrumentation for the app,
> while the android-agent includes the harvesting and collection logic
> for the agent. If you don’t apply that plugin, no instrumentation of
> the app occurs, and when the agent starts, an error will be thrown for
> a lack of instrumentation.
>
> The agent gradle plugin sets up gradle tasks necessary for the agent;
> The class-rewriter performs bytecode manipulation at compile time, and
> will not run unless the agent gradle plugin has created the
> appropriate tasks.
>
> Currently, we only support gradle as previous configuration options
> (Ant, Eclipse, and Maven plugins) have been discontinued/deprecated.